# Why is shared_ptr implemented using control block and not a static map?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, std

To me, it looks like an implementation of `std::shared_ptr` which stores a reference counter in a `static std::unordered_map<void*, struct Counters>` would be much more simpler and also allow us to avoid some dirty workarounds like `std::enable_shared_from_this` (because `std::shared_ptr<T>{this}` wouldn't create new control block, only increment a counter for a pointer that already exists in a map).

So why does a committee decided to stick with a control block implementation?

Comment: How would you implement weak references? Those can stay around even after the managed object is gone. And aliasing? You may not have access to the "containing" pointer to use as key. Still simple?

Comment: [@StoryTeller - Unslander Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller-unslander-monica): Okay, so then weak references could be implemented, if a value stored in a map would contain two counters: one for strong references and one for weak (as it is in a current implementation). Aliasing would be a bit harder, but still not impossible.

Comment: There would have to be a different `static std::map<T*, size_t>` for each `T` unless you can get some form of type erasure to work.

Comment: @RichardCritten you'd probably want it to be `void*` anyway, because the object owned isn't necessarily the object pointed to

Comment: Complexity (big O) would be different too.

Comment: I think I'll address some of your remarks in a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why does a committee decided to stick with a control block implementation?

It doesn't. The committee writes requirements that implementers must follow. They do not specify that `std::shared_ptr` be implemented in any particular way, so long as that way meets the requirements.

Having said that, your proposed `static std::map<T*, size_t>` runs foul of this general (unless otherwise specified) requirement:

> A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly
> access objects ([intro.multithread]) accessible by threads other than
> the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or
> indirectly via the function's arguments, including `this`.

[`[res.on.data.races#2]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/res.on.data.races#2)

Another compelling reason is that `std::shared_ptr` type-erases the deleter, so at best you'd have a `static std::map<void *, struct { size_t count; size_t weak_count; std::function<void(void*)> deleter; }>`, at which point you have *two* dynamic allocations for the control block, rather than the *one* (possibly merged with the owned object) that current implementers prefer.